# how to call view in extjs on button click event

Tags: extjs, yii

i am working in extjs+ Yii framework. I have  view as-
QbQns.js-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.Qbqns',    
        {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires:[
              'Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsView'
              ],
              id:'qbqnsId',
              alias:'widget.Qbqns',
              title:'Qbqns',
              height:500,
              items:[
                     { xtype:'QbqnsView',},
                     ],//end of items square
                     buttons:[
                              { xtype:'button',
                                  fieldLabel:'Vote',
                                  action:'voteAction',
                                  name:'vote',
                                  formBind:true,
                                  text:'submit', } ] });
```

On this submit button click, i want to create new view as-

```
 Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsReviewView',
    {
            extend:'Ext.view.View',
            id:'qbqnsViewId',
            alias:'widget.QbqnsReviewView',
            //store:'kp.PollStore',
            store:'qb.QbqnsStore',
            config:
            {
                tpl:'<tpl for=".">'+
                    '<div id="main">'+
                    '</br>'+

                    '<h1 id="q">Question :-</h1> {question}</br>'+

                 /*  '<tpl for="options">'+     // interrogate the kids property within the data
                        '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{parent.questionId}" value="{option}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
                    '</tpl>'+*/

                    '<tpl for="options">'+
                        '<tpl if="parent.Correctoption==option">'+
                        //'<tpl if="Correctoption==UsersOption">'+
                        '<p style="color:Green"><input type="radio" name="{optionId}">{option}</p>'+

                        '<tpl elseif="parent.UsersOption==option">'+
                        '<p style="color:Red"><input type="radio" name="{optionId}">{option}</p>'+

                        '<tpl else>'+
                        '<p><input type="radio" name="{parent.questionId}" value="{option}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+

                        '</tpl>'+  
                    '</tpl>'+   



     '<p>---------------------------------------------------------</p>'+
                    '</div>'+

                   '<h1 id="q">Total marks are:-</h1>{Total}'+
                   '<h1 id="q">Score you got is:-</h1>{Score}'+

                    '</tpl>',



                itemSelector:'div.main',
            }
    });// End of login class
```

So how to call this above view from controller on submit button click. Please suggest me...

Comment: Can someone please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'button[action=voteAction]': {
            click: function(btn) {
                Ext.create('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsReviewView', {
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody();  //<-- where you want render it
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Also the store in your view is a string now. Use Ext.create() or Ext.getStore(storeId).

Can be you need read a [guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture)?

Comment: thanx sir for reply...Actully sir i had tried as you have suggested. But its giving me error as QbqnsReviewview not found error. i hve declared all views in controller also.

Comment: @user2077845 Do your QbqnsReviewView.js file placed in /Balaee/view/qb/qbqns dir?

Comment: yes sir...its in /Balaee/view/qb/qbqns folder. But still its giving me error as file not found...

Comment: Ext.define('Balaee.controller.qb.QbqnsController',{
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
 stores: ['qb.QbqnsStore','qb.QbquestionoptionStore'],
 models: ['qb.QbqnsModel','qb.QbqnsoptionModel','qb.QbquestionoptionModel'],
 views: ['qb.qbqns.Qbqns','qb.qbqns.QbqnsView','qb.qbqns.QbqnsReview'],
 
 init: function() {
  console.log("Inside question controller");
  this.control({
   'Qbqns button[action=voteAction]': 
   {click:this.check}, 
  });
 },
 check:function()
 {
   
Ext.create('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsReviewView', {
 renderTo: Ext.getBody(),  }); 
}
});    Its my controller code.

Comment: @user2077845 Try change 'qb.qbqns.QbqnsReview' in 'views' on 'qb.qbqns.QbqnsReviewView'

Comment: So it's not there ... Perhaps a case difference in names.